# Why Does Quad Topology Not Always Result in Correct Shading?

Tags: shaders, topology

Why does quad topology not always result in correct shading? Sure on a cube like this its easy enough to toss on a weighted normal/autosmooth, but why does this happen, and is there any way to rectify it through better topology?

[image: Quad topo with incorrect shading]

[image: Good cube]

Comment: if you've smooth shaded it it will try to smooth even between flat faces, in that case you need to enable Auto Smooth to determine the angle

Answer (score 2):

The only thing comes to mind is the software tries to preserve data.
be it smoothing data. until you change it manually it tries to keep it that way.

So that's means more control to you and what you create.

Edit: here is an Image from https://github.com/fedackb/yavne
[image]

You could also say software does not know what you want and just does the default calculations.
depending on what you want I would say every artist would prefer one of them over the other.